# assigning an integer in a conditional statement

Tags: c++

I wanted to assign to currentDistance the returned value CountBitDifference. Instead it returns to me a 0 or 1 depending on the conditional statement being false or true. Is there a way to assign the currentDistance value in the conditional statement or I will have to do it somewhere else.

```
if (int currentDistance = CountBitDifference(m0.ptr<unsigned char>(matches[i].queryIdx),
                                    m1.ptr<unsigned char>(matches[i].trainIdx),
                                    cascadeSize, cascadeByteIndex) >= 8)
```

Comment: Placing the initialization before the `if` doesn't hurt. Putting it inside does. Choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code initializes `currentDistance` to the result of `>=`. If you want to assign `currentDistance` the value returned from `CountBitDifference`, *and* compare that value to 8 -- all in the same expression -- you'll need parentheses.

```
int currentDistance;
if ( ( currentDistance = CountBitDifference(m0.ptr<unsigned char>(matches[i].queryIdx),
                                    m1.ptr<unsigned char>(matches[i].trainIdx),
                                    cascadeSize, cascadeByteIndex)) >= 8)
```

Or, more clearly:

```
int currentDistance = CountBitDifference(m0.ptr<unsigned char>(matches[i].queryIdx),
                                    m1.ptr<unsigned char>(matches[i].trainIdx),
                                    cascadeSize, cascadeByteIndex);
if(currentDistance >= 8)
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, I am already following the latter method, but I was just looking if the first method above was possible. Thanks for telling me about the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

First I would dump to log to confirm that your CountBitDifference expression is doing what it is supposed to do. If it is, it seems like perhaps a weird scoping error. Would it kill you to define and intialise currentDistance prior to assigning it in the statement?

Also the if statement checks for whether this function succeeded or not... why are you doing this?

**Edit:** I totally missed the comparison at the end of the expression. This is a bit kludgy, I would seriously consider breaking it out into a function that returns a boolean. Also 8 is a magic number.

**Edit:** Try this, return an integer and as a function to encourage re-use.

```
public int getBitDifference() {

    //assumes you have declared your variables in a greater scope
    //otherwise you will have to pass your variables to the function... hard to say
    //without seeing all the code

    return CountBitDifference(m0.ptr<unsigned char>(matches[i].queryIdx),
                                m1.ptr<unsigned char>(matches[i].trainIdx),
                                cascadeSize, cascadeByteIndex)


}
```

And then:

```
if (getBitDifference() >= 8) {

//do stuff here

}
```

Much more readable. Also declare 8 as a constant BIT_DISTANCE_MARGIN to avoid use of magic number, so

```
if (getBitDifference() >= BIT_DISTANCE_MARGIN) {

//do stuff here

}
```

and you've got yourself some readable, maintainable code.

Comment: I just put 8 there but I already have BIT_TOLERANCE in my code. I just wanted to keep it simple for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (int currentDistance = CountBitDifference(m0.ptr<unsigned char>(matches[i].queryIdx),
                                    m1.ptr<unsigned char>(matches[i].trainIdx),
                                    cascadeSize, cascadeByteIndex) >= 8)
```

Is just too hard to read. Try the following code.

```
 int currentDistance = CountBitDifference(m0.ptr<unsigned char>(matches[i].queryIdx) 
                                           ,m1.ptr<unsigned char>(matches[i].trainIdx)
                                           ,cascadeSize, cascadeByteIndex);
   if(currentDistance >= 8) { }
```

Also remember, when someone is reading your code, may be you on a later date, they/you may not remember the associativity of `=` and `>=` operators and precedence of one over the other. Hence it is a good idea to just break the two statements into multiple lines. Readability is important, unnecessary brevity is foolishness.

Comment: There is no `=` operator in either line. There is only an initializer.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any reason why you want to do this...

It's just as easy to initialise before the if statement and more readable. If you don't need to keep the value of CountBitDifference why can't you just do this:

```
if (CountBitDifference(m0.ptr<unsigned char>(matches[i].queryIdx),
                                m1.ptr<unsigned char>(matches[i].trainIdx),
                                cascadeSize, cascadeByteIndex) >= 8)
```

And if you need to keep it just do this:

```
int currentDistance = CountBitDifference(m0.ptr<unsigned char>(matches[i].queryIdx),
                                m1.ptr<unsigned char>(matches[i].trainIdx),
                                cascadeSize, cascadeByteIndex);

if (currentDistance >= 8)
```